# When and why to use Boxed accounts

Tags: anchor, rust, web3.js

The documentation regarding [Boxed accounts](https://docs.rs/anchor-lang/latest/anchor_lang/accounts/boxed/index.html) is a bit scarce:

> "Box type to save stack space. Sometimes accounts are too large for the stack, leading to stack violations.
> Boxing the account can help."

What exactly is Boxing an account? When exactly should be used and how do they work? Are there any limits or constraints of using Boxing in Solana?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All memory lives on either the stack or the heap. By default, Anchor loads account data onto the stack, but each stack frame on Solana is only 4KB so you can use up that memory rather quickly. When the stack limit is execeeded, you'll get an error at compile time which looks something like this:

```
Error: Function _ZN16curve25519_dalek7edwards21EdwardsBasepointTable6create17h178b3d2411f7f082E Stack offset of -30728 exceeded max offset of -4096 by 26632 bytes, please minimize large stack variables
```

`Box` is a memory management tool which allows you to allocate account memory on the heap instead. It gives you a pointer to the heap memory where your account data is stored. This helps save on stack space. For very large accounts, boxing may not be enough and you may run out of heap space as well. In these situations, you should look into zero-copy accounts.

Read more:

- https://docs.solana.com/developing/on-chain-programs/overview#memory-map
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap
- https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html
- https://docs.rs/anchor-lang/0.13.2/anchor_lang/trait.ZeroCopy.html