# anchor build -> stack offset exceeding max offset

Tags: solana-program, anchor-lang, anchor-spl

they said you can use like 30 accounts, i have only ten and already exceed the stack limit. five associated token accounts, two mints, a pda, the payer, and the token program.

Comment: I have just created hello world program and still i get stack exceeded.Any clue ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it works, but try to encapsulate them in `box<>`, By default all the accounts in anchor are stored in stack, But by using `Box` it will move them to a heap. You can Find more in detail [Here](https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/4931/1174)

Comment: are remaining_accounts also put on the stack in anchor?

Comment: yes, most likely

Comment: Box<Account<'info, token::TokenAccount>> works great!